# New record Create option not available in lookup field in <lightning-input-field> tag

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lookup, lightning-inputfield

All I have a requirement to create a custom Case form with few fields. In Contact lookup, I am not able to see the option to create Contact. Can anyone guide me what I am missing in the code.

[image]

HTML:

```
<template>
<lightning-card>
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Case" onsuccess={handleSuccess} onsubmit ={handleSubmit}>
    <lightning-messages>
    </lightning-messages>
    <lightning-input-field field-name='ContactId'></lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name='Subject'></lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name='Description'></lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name='Origin'></lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" type="submit" label="Create Case">
    </lightning-button>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

Javascript:

```
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';

export default class NewRecCreate extends LightningElement {
    handleSuccess(event) {
        console.log('onsuccess event recordEditForm',event.detail.id)
    }
    handleSubmit(event) {
        console.log('onsubmit event recordEditForm'+ event.detail.fields);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's all standard Salesforce UI, we don't get everything in the Standard LWC components, for this we have to write custom logic, create a custom LWC component which can do what lightning-input-field is doing for reference fields and then add option to allow New record.

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

An extract from the documentation says:

**Creating a new record from the lookup field's dropdown menu is currently not supported.**

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/documentation

Answer (score 0):

I would check out this [link](https://salesforcediaries.com/2020/03/20/reusable-custom-lookup-field-in-lightning-web-component/).They are able to create a reusable lookup field. I would then append a value '+ New Record' that when selected opens a model to [create a new record](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_create_record). Then you can capture the new record Id and place that into the lookup field.

You can also look at this [example](https://www.salesforcepoint.com/2020/07/dynamic-reusable-custom-lwc-lookup.html).

Either way, append an option to the drop down then look for onchange to see if that option was chosen then prompt the new record create.